# Why values of getTime of two same dates are different

Tags: javascript, v8

The code is as follows.

```
let dateString1 = '2019-4';
let dateString2 = '2019-04';

(new Date(dateString1).getTime()) == (new Date(dateString2).getTime()) // false #comparison1
new Date(dateString1).getTime(); // 1554058800000 #time1
new Date(dateString2).getTime(); // 1554076800000 #time2
```

I know why `#comparison1` is `false`. I just want to know the reason why `#time1` and `#time2` are two different values? Shouldn't these values be same?

Comment: `2019-4` or `2019-04` is not a valid date.

Comment: when you pass these values to Date object, it gives me the same date

Comment: @Lain why the comparison is false is because these two time values are different. I want to know why these two values are different on the basis on passed date strings?

Comment: `(new Date('2019-4').getTime()) === (new Date('2019-04').getTime())` gives true for me (firefox).

Comment: @RolandStarke it is giving me false on google-chrome v8 engine

Comment: When you use a malformed date is will try and decode in locale time, if you on the other hand start to send a ISO date, it will use UTC.    But in both cases a none valid date to the date constructor is not supported.

Comment: @MukarramIshaq "when you pass these values to Date object, it gives me the same date" ...maybe, but not the same _time_. https://jsfiddle.net/879ujzty/ . You are providing invalid strings for it to parse, so you can't expect predictable behaviour from the Date engine anyway. Keith is right about the way it attempts to interpret what you've provided, but it's only an attempt, not a guaranteed functionality.

Comment: You can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) to get documentation (there is more in-depth detail in the links which are provided there as well) about what is considered a valid date/time string which you can pass to the JS Date constructor and get predictable, documented, supported behaviour in return.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the documentation link. It surely helped me.

Comment: @MukarramIshaq No problem. In my (humble) opinion,  MDN should be the go-to place to look when you want to know something about how JavaScript, HTML, CSS etc are supposed to work. There is a lot of detail and it's usually very accurate.